# Gaps in the proof of the fact that Lipschitz condition implies uniform convergence of the Fourier series.

Tags: fourier-analysis, proof-explanation, fourier-series, uniform-convergence

> If $f$ satisfies a Lipschitz condition, then $S_Nf\to f$ uniformly as $N\to \infty$ where $S_N$ is the $N$-th partial sum of the Fourier series.

I learnt the 'proof' of the above theorem from this [lecture note](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.csun.edu/%7Eac53971/courses/math650/fourier.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjB2a6TjvzqAhWvyYsBHXquA4oQFjACegQIBRAB&usg=AOvVaw2cYnAyf6yWf7Qj2THHCSso). Let me outline its main idea:

> \begin{aligned}
> \left|S_{N} f(x)-f(x)\right| &=\left|\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{2 \pi}(f(x-t)-f(x)) D_{N}(t) d t \right|\\
> &=\left|\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(f(x-t)-f(x)) D_{N}(t) d t \right|\\
> &=\left|\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(f(x-t)-f(x)) \frac{\sin \left(N+\frac{1}{2}\right) t}{\sin (t / 2)} d t\right|\\&\le \frac{1}{2 \pi}\left|\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(f(x-t)-f(x)) \frac{\cos (t / 2)}{\sin (t / 2)} \sin N t d t\right| + \frac{1}{2 \pi}\left|\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(f(x-t)-f(x)) \cos N t d t\right|
> \end{aligned}

> Let $\color{red}{h(t)=(f(x-t)-f(t)) \frac{\cos (t / 2)}{\sin (t / 2)}}$ for $t\neq 0$, $\color{red}{k(t)=f(x-t)-f(t)}$, then the Lipschitz condition says $|h(t)|$ is continuous and bounded except for the point $0$, thus $|h|^2$ is integrable. So is $|k|^2$. By the corollary to the Bessel's inequality, $\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} h(t) \sin N t d t\to 0$. Similarly, $\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} k(t) \cos N t d t \to0$. But these are exactly the two terms on the right hand side. QED

However, I am skeptical about whether the above proof establishes the *uniform* convergence of $S_Nf(x)$. As the definition of $h(t)$ and $k(t)$ depends on $x$, how can we be sure that the $N$ can be chosen independent of $x$? I have also checked out the proof of the corollary to the Bessel's inequality (i.e. the Fourier coefficients of $f$ goes to $0$ as $N\to \infty$ provided that $|f|^2$ is integrable), it is proved by noting that $\sum a_n$ converges implies $a_n\to 0$, which is a pretty roundabout way (albeit clever) to demonstrate the result. In particular, I don't see how to modify it so that choosing a single $N$ suffices for all $x$. Please help me fill in the gaps in this proof. Many thanks!

Comment: As far as I can see this 'proof' is not at all a proof. It cannot be easily rectified. I suggest looking at Fourier Series by Edwards for a proof.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks, I will look it up.

Comment: the notes have a mistake as $h(t)=(f(x-t)-f(x)) \frac{\cos (t / 2)}{\sin (t / 2)}$ so by Lipschitz, $|h(t)| \le C, t \ne 0$ uniformly in $x$ so the proof follows (for $k(t)$ which is correct, Lipschitz gives $k(t)| \le C|t|$ again uniformly in $x$ but that term is the trivial part where continuity of $f$ is enough to show uniform convergence to zero - the difficult term is the one that has the $\sin t/2$ in the denominator as that is generally unbounded, non-integrable etc unless $f(x-t)-f(x)$ decays fast enough to zero for $t \to 0$ - for arbitrary continuous $f$ the decay may be very slow

Comment: You could use the fact that the uniform Lipschitz condition forces $f$ to be absolutely continuous on the interval of interest, with a derivative that exists a.e. on that interval, and the derivative is uniformly bounded by $M$, taken from the Lipschitz condition. Then you could integrate by parts. You'll get uniform convergence on any closed interval strictly contained in the open interval where it is Lipschitz, but not on the entire closed interval.